# JMeter Http request response timeout does not seem to work in certain conditions

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am sending a http request to a server which has timeout:0 for this type of connections (it basically keeps the connection open).

I am trying to set a `Response timeout` in the `HTTP Request sampler` in the `Advanced tab`.

- for 40000ms(40secs) the connection is stopped and I get what I want `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`
- for 50000ms(50sec) or more the connection is never closed.

I do not know the actual value for which the connection is not closed.

The question is, if anyone encountered this before, and if they found a solution?
I can't seem to figure if it is a JMeter bug, an OS parameter-ish or maybe I just configured it wrong, or w/e.

Comment: I had similar issue and adding `Connection` with value `close` in Header Manager helped

Comment: request timeout resets every time client gets anything from the server, so maybe what is happening is: if you set it to 40sec, it's not enough time to get anything at all; if you set it to longer, then client gets something after (say) 50sec, and starts waiting for 50 sec again, gets something again, and so on... I'd use fiddler/wireshark to check that theory

Comment: Got with wireshark to see what happens. It seems that the server periodicaly sends `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` and this might be what resets the `Response` timeout. If this really is the case, should JMeter work like this ?